# Returning a PLSQL Cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which contains schedule information. Depending on the situation I may wish to select all schedule information for a driving serial or I may want to select based on start and end dates. This is quite a generic thing to want to do.

I then have a function which requires said schedule information but something inside the method will decide whether a start date is required or not.

So I want something like this:

```
    getCursor(serial, startdate, enddate)
```

Inside my function:

```
    if something or other:
      cursor = getCursor(serial, null, null)
    else
      cursor = getCursor(serial, start, null)

    Loop around cursor
```

Any idea about how to get this behaviour? I have looked around and seen various different methods but haven't been able to get any of them to work. Is what I want to do event the right approach in PL/SQL? It's not a language I often use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not obvious to me that you need an `IF` statement or any recursion.  It sounds like you just want

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getSchedule( p_serial IN table_name.serial%type,
                                        p_start_date IN DATE DEFAULT NULL,
                                        p_end_date IN DATE DEFAULT NULL )
  RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
  l_schedule_rc sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_schedule_rc
   FOR SELECT *
         FROM table_name
        WHERE serial = p_serial
          AND (p_start_date IS NULL or start_date >= p_start_date)
          AND (p_end_date IS NULL   or end_date   <= p_end_date);
  RETURN l_schedule_rc;
END;
```

This allows the start and end dates to be optional parameters and your query ignores the dates if the parameters input are `NULL` or are omitted.  Of course, this assumes that you have a calling program that knows how to call a PL/SQL function that returns a `sys_refcursor`...

Comment: That looks similar to what I've seen before.

My calling program wants to then do a calculation based on the rows returned. The rows returned will depend on whether or not a start date is needed. Thinking about it the IF statement isn't really needed. I just pass in startdate and it deals with it being null.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not need a special function for you issue.
Try this:

```
-- Retruns all rows that start_date is between p_from and p_to
SELECT *
  FROM table_name t
 WHERE t.serial = p_serial
   AND t.start_date BETWEEN NVL(p_from, t.start_date) 
                        AND NVL(p_to  , t.start_date)
```